# What did Jacobi, who lived before Riemann, have to do with the equation and theorem named after him in Riemannian geometry?

Tags: mathematics, differential-geometry

In Riemannian geometry we have two very important things named after Jacobi: the Jacobi equation $J''=R(\gamma',J)\gamma'$ and Jacobi's theorem which states geodesics never minimize past conjugate points. Why is Jacobi's name attached to this equation and theorem?

Answer (score 5):

This is a natural question given the modern exposition, where Riemannian geometry is often the only place where some parts of the calculus of variations are encountered. And a reminder that historical order rarely follows the order of modern expositions. Jacobi's equation, condition, fields, etc., are not specific to Riemannian geometry, they relate to the second variation of functionals in the classical calculus of variations like $\int_a^b f(x,y,y')\,dx$, the arclength functional of the geodesic problem is just a particular case. Those were in the sights of the leading mathematicians since the [brachistochrone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve#History).

According to [Ferguson's Brief Survey of the History of the Calculus  of Variations and its Applications](https://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0402/0402357.pdf), Legendre in 1786 presented a memoir On  the  Method  of  Distinguishing  Maxima  from  Minima  in  the  Calculus  of  Variations, where he showed that necessarily $f_{y',y'}\geq0$ for minimizers, and $\leq0$ for maximizers. Half a century later Jacobi "*in  a  paper  remarkable  for  its  brevity  and  obscurity*" gave a complementary sufficient condition, $f_{y',y'}>0$ and $b$ is closer to $a$ than the first conjugate point of $a$. The paper, On the Calculus of Variations and the Theory of Differential Equations (1836),

> "*was so terse that rigourous  proofs were not  given but instead were hinted at. Perhaps, as one mathematical historian has suggested, Jacobi was in a rush to publish his results first to ensure intellectual priority. It is difficult to agree with such a theory since  progress  in  this  field  had  stagnated  for  half  a  century!*"

Thus, after another half a century Riemannian geometry became a natural place for applying Jacobi's result. The "one historian" is Goldstine, and more details can be found in his [History of the Calculus of Variations from the 17th through the 19th Century](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461381082).

Comment: What equation of Jacobi's is the modern version named after (presumably he had an equation similar to it)?

Comment: @0celo7 It is reproduced under the link but too cumbersome for me to copy it here. Jacobi didn't have the benefit of slick modern notation :)